# Get numbers (including "-") with non leading zero

Tags: regex

I want to match numbers including "-" with non leading zeros and normal numbers without "-". Therefore I want to use a regular expression.

The regex
should match `0 1 2 3 123 2-3 22-33`
 and 
should not match `0123-123 01234`.

The following regex works nearly:

```
\b(0|[1-9][0-9]*\-?[0-9]*)\b
```

The numbers 0 1 2 3 123 2-3 22-33 and 01234 are matched correctly, but 0123-123 not: it is matched partly. https://regex101.com/r/0Po3Ed/1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a negative lookbehind in your regex:

```
(?<!-)\b(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*(?:-[0-9]+)?)\b
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Po3Ed/2)

`(?<!-)` is negative lookbehind expressions that will fail the match if you have `-` before numbers.